# R-Markdown centering a kable releative to the screen

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown, kable

I'm using the following code to generate three tables.
However, the tables have many columns and my table gets pushed to the right (centers in relation to its containing div, which is already centered to the page).

How can I center the table with relation to the screen itself?

````
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(pander)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '', width = 1980)

for (i in 1:length(reports)) {
  current_report <- reports[[i]]
  cat("### Report ", i, "\n")
  print(current_report %>% 
          kable("html", row.names = FALSE, align = "l")  %>%
          kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", font_size = 12))
  cat("\n", "\n")
}
```
````

Comment: Hey, just to make sure that I understand correctly, you essentially want your table to fit on the current page? So use the full width of the page but no more? Also going by your code you want HTML output?